# List all Kubelet path endpoints

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

A Kubelet has several endpoint paths it listens on, such as `/metrics`, `/metrics/cadvisor`, `/logs`, etc. One can easily query these endpoints by running `kubectl get --raw /api/v1/nodes/<node-name>/proxy/<path>` (after running `kubectl proxy`).

My question is how can one obtain the list of all these paths that Kubelet is serving? A list can be found in the Kubelet's own code [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go#L84), but that's just a subset. There's for example `/pods` which is not on that list, but defined further down in [the code as well](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go#L342). But there are others that aren't explicitly listed in the code, such as `/healthz`, which one guesses by looking at [other lines of the code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go#L333). I'd also venture to believe that other addons or 3rd party products could result in the Kubelet exposing more paths.

I tried using `/healthz?verbose`, but it only returns basic information, and nothing near a list of paths:

```
[+]ping ok
[+]log ok
[+]syncloop ok
healthz check passed
```

The Kubernetes API Server returns a very nice list of paths using `kubectl get --raw /` as seen below (truncated due to length). Is there something equivalent for Kubelet's own paths?

```
{
  "paths": [
    "/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    "/api",
    "/api/v1",
    "/apis",
    "/apis/",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apps",
    "/apis/apps/v1",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/autoscaling",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v1",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v2beta1",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v2beta2",
    "/apis/batch",
    "/apis/batch/v1",
    "/apis/batch/v1beta1",
    "/apis/certificates.k8s.io",
....
```

Comment: According to the official documentation [the kubelet is the primary "node agent" that runs on each node. It can register the node with the apiserver. The kubelet takes a set of PodSpecs that are provided through various mechanisms (primarily through the apiserver) and ensures that the containers described in those PodSpecs are running and healthy.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/#synopsis) Sure, there is no well described information about usage of kubelet API.

Comment: But at the same time there is no too much cases to interact with kubelet endpoints directly even with kubernetes API. It means that for interacting with kubernetes API we are using kubectl/binary.
Some information about kubelet API can be found in this [article](https://www.deepnetwork.com/blog//2020/01/13/kubelet-api.html) and it seems that the best solution for finding more details about particular endpoint is to look at the moment into the [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go) since it isn't documented anywhere.

Comment: Based on the provided information: Why we should interact with kubelet directly, what is the use case?

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin One reason for having this list is to be able to see at a glance what specific components are running inside the Kubelet. For example, the Summary API endpoint is at /stats/summary, the Resource Metrics endpoint is at /metrics/resource while the cAdvisor one is now at /metrics/cAdvisor. As there are changes coming up around the monitoring components (e.g. Summary API will eventually be deprecated) seeing whether a specific endpoint is there gives quick feedback about what's running

Comment: But I agree, this isn't something you'll want in your daily interactions with a K8s cluster

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information from different sources, below provided some endpoints for kubelet.

From the code of [kubelet server](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.23/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go#L85):

```
/metrics
/metrics/cadvisor
/metrics/resource
/metrics/probes
/stats/
/logs/
/debug/pprof/
/debug/flags/v
```

[also](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.23/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go#L342):

```
/pods/*
```

[and](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.23/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go#L409):

```
/run/*
/exec/*
/attach/*
/portForward/*
/containerLogs/*
/configz
/runningpods/
```

[here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.23/pkg/kubelet/server/auth_test.go#L108):

```
"/attach/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{containerName}":       "proxy",
"/attach/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{uid}/{containerName}": "proxy",
"/configz": "proxy",
"/containerLogs/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{containerName}": "proxy",
"/debug/flags/v":                                     "proxy",
"/debug/pprof/{subpath:*}":                           "proxy",
"/exec/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{containerName}":       "proxy",
"/exec/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{uid}/{containerName}": "proxy",
"/healthz":                            "proxy",
"/healthz/log":                        "proxy",
"/healthz/ping":                       "proxy",
"/healthz/syncloop":                   "proxy",
"/logs/":                              "log",
"/logs/{logpath:*}":                   "log",
"/metrics":                            "metrics",
"/metrics/cadvisor":                   "metrics",
"/metrics/probes":                     "metrics",
"/metrics/resource":                   "metrics",
"/pods/":                              "proxy",
"/portForward/{podNamespace}/{podID}": "proxy",
"/portForward/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{uid}":         "proxy",
"/run/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{containerName}":       "proxy",
"/run/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{uid}/{containerName}": "proxy",
"/runningpods/":  "proxy",
"/stats/":        "stats",
"/stats/summary": "stats"
```

The asterisk indicates that full request should be updated with some parameters. For example for `/containerLogs/*` with adding `/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{containerName}`:

```
kubectl get --raw /api/v1/nodes/<node-name>/proxy/containerLogs/{podNamespace}/{podID}/{containerName}
```

Some information [from kubernetes site about kubelet API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#kubelet-authorization):

```
/stats/*
/metrics/*
/logs/*
/spec/*
```

Also you can look at this page from [kubeletctl](https://github.com/cyberark/kubeletctl/blob/master/API_TABLE.md). It's a bit outdated, but may provide some useful information about the kubelet API and HTTP requests.

And this [article about the kubelet API](https://www.deepnetwork.com/blog/2020/01/13/kubelet-api.html) is good too.

In any case, it is recommended to check the kubernetes documentation before using it to see what is deprecated in current / old releases.

p.s. If you are interested in this topic, you can create an issue on [kubernetes GitHub page](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues) to propose an improvement for kubelet documentation.